# Retrieving and displaying data based on time period

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

the following code retrieve all activities start and end in the same date that  picked  by user , what i need retrieve all activities that the date picked by user in the period of the activate

for example
  activity start on 25 march and end on 25 march too that the code will retrieve but what i need is to retrieve activities started before 25 and end after 25 or start before 25 and end in 25 and activities start on 25 and after 25

OR YOU CAN SEE MY PIC MY CODE IS DOING A BUT I WANT TO DO A , B ,C AND D
http://im46.gulfup.com/4Cudk8.jpg

```
 Public Shared Function SelectByDate(ActivityDate As Date) As List(Of vActivity)

        Dim st As Date = ActivityDate
        Dim et As Date = st.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)

       Using ctx As New ActivitiesEntities
            Dim Lst = (From actv In ctx.vActivities
                       Select actv
                       Where actv.StartTime >= st And actv.EndTime <= et
                       Order By actv.StartTime)

            Return Lst.ToList
        End Using
    End Function
```

Comment: you just want to know what records where a user-supplied datetime is between the start and end time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim LstA = (From actv In ctx.vActivities
                       Select actv
                       Where actv.StartTime >= st And actv.EndTime <= et
                       Order By actv.StartTime)

Dim LstB = (From actv In ctx.vActivities
                       Select actv
                       Where actv.StartTime < st And actv.EndTime < st
                       Order By actv.StartTime)

Dim LstC = (From actv In ctx.vActivities
                       Select actv
                       Where actv.StartTime > et And actv.EndTime > et
                       Order By actv.StartTime)

Dim LstD = (From actv In ctx.vActivities
                       Select actv
                       Order By actv.StartTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Where actv.StartTime <= usertime And actv.EndTime >= usertime
```

Your question is a bit confusing, but this seems like what you're describing.

Your screenshot is blocked from my work but: if you want A or B or C.. just write your where clause as such.

```
where (actv.StartTime <= usertime And actv.EndTime >= usertime) or (something else) or (something else)
```

Comment: MY CODE DO A BUT I WANT TO DO A , B , C AND D   http://im46.gulfup.com/4Cudk8.jpg